# Why does ruby's IO.read add a newline?

Tags: ruby, io

```
$ echo testing > testfile
$ irb
2.5.1 :001 > IO.read('testfile')
=> "testing\n"
```

Trying to understand where the newline is coming from as it's clearly not in the file.

Comment: "Trying to understand where the newline is coming from as it's clearly not in the file." – How have you determined that "it's clearly not in the file"? According to the commands you posted, there "clearly" *should* be a newline in the file, unless your `echo` is broken.

Comment: My test was opening it in vim, but that wasn't good enough. Apparently my echo is functioning as documented. #PEBKAC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But the newline is in the file, `echo` adds it. You can see for yourself with a hexdump:

```
$ echo testing > testfile
$ hexdump testfile 
0000000 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67 0a                        
0000008
```

That `0x0a` is your newline.

And you can ask your shell (presumably `bash`) about `echo`:

```
$ help echo
echo: echo [-neE] [arg ...]
    Output the ARGs.  If -n is specified, the trailing newline is
    suppressed. [...]
```

So if you say `echo -n testing > testfile`, you'll get the results that you're expecting.

Comment: Clean answer. It may be worth mentioning that text files should end with a newline if you want to conform to the standard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline